# Can I prevent a Canon Selphy CP1300 from aggressively cropping images?

Tags: macos, printing

Photos are quite aggressively cropped when printed from Photos to a Canon Selphy CP1300 photo printer. This also occurs when printing from Preview, and I would expect it to be the same whatever application is used, because I suspect that the issue is probably the printer itself.

Print settings: 100x148mm, borderless (Canon's driver calls it "Postcard").

This is not just a case of cropping to fit the aspect ratio of the 100x148mm photo paper. It crops substantial amounts from all four sides of an image. The preview of the image in the printer dialog is pretty inaccurate - the yellow border below shows the amount of material that is lost when printing.

[image: Incorrectly cropped image]

In most cases, it's no more than mildly annoying, but it ruins some where the edges of the photo really matter.

I'm guessing the culprit is probably the printer rather than the driver, because the same image output as PDF via the same driver is correct.

Is there some way to prevent this? If it's the printer doing this with the image it receives then it's really problematic. There are some that I could resize to try to counteract the cropping, but that's a) an idiotic thing to have to do and b) impossible in some cases.

Comment: "When printed from macOS" doesn't tell us what App you are using. Also when printing what options are you selecting in page setup. Please edit your original question and add that info so that we have enough to go on to assist you.

Comment: @SteveChambers Done, but I am pretty certain this is application-independent.

Comment: That is what needs to be determined. A couple of things to try: first another App that you can print your pictures with. Second try a different Canon driver. Usually there are few differences between (mostly) similar models of printer. Printing with another driver might point to where the problem is. Also macOS uses the UNIX CUPS printing system. Often CUPS drivers can be made to work on macOS. I would Google CUPS for macOS to familiarize yourself and see if you can find a compatible CUPS driver.

Comment: Sadly I can confirm that it seems to be completely independent of the driver: if I print an image from an SD card, the preview on the printer's own screen shows the same preview as in the macOS driver, but it still crops all the edges when the image is printed. Perhaps this is a more suitable question for Photos StackExchange now.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130835/can-a-canon-selphy-printer-cp1300-be-configured-to-print-borderless-photos-wit

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't seem possible to prevent this from happening. The same behaviour is observed when printing from an image on an SD card attached directly to the printer - so this is not in fact related to macOS at all.